# showing images while uploading multiple images

Tags: angularjs

i have done multiple image upload using angular directive.my directive look like below

```
    app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,        //create a new scope
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
                for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                    //emit event upward
                    scope.$emit("fileSelected", {file: files[i] });
                }                                       
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my controller pushed all selected files into array

```
$scope.files = [];
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () { 
        $scope.files.push(args.file);
    });
});
```

In my view file i used ng-repeat to show all selected images.my view page code look like below

```
<div ng-repeat="step in files">
<img ng-src="{{step}}" />{{step.name}}
</div>
```

but here my problem is i can only show the image name but i want to show all selected images instead of names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display currently selected file you could read it using `FileReader` API and provided that base64 string inside img src.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" file-upload /> {{files.length}}
<div ng-repeat="step in files">
  <img ng-src="{{step.src}}" />{{step.src}}
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function(event, args) {
  var item = args;
  $scope.files.push(item);
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      item.src = reader.result;
    });
  }, false);

  if (item.file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(item.file);
  }
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3X3sb2yZRmUPCA46EYV?p=preview)

Comment: when i click submit button it goes to api(PHP).how can i get file details in api?

Comment: @user7098427 you have to send file to API(`POST`) call

Comment: because when i use this code i get data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD etc...so how is this possible?

Comment: Actually what is the meaning of image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD etc in ng-repeat {{step.src}}.

Comment: It is `base64` version of image. You could consider sending `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD` out of `image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD`. But when you're using it on src, you should have `image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD`

Comment: could u make it for plunkr to get image info in server side?

Comment: This seems to be just beyond the question, what you have asked. Please consider opening new question for the same

Comment: can you consider below question if u donot mind    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250848/send-multiple-image-data-with-textbox-from-angular-controller